# splitting of csv file based on column value in java

Tags: java, csv, drools

I want to split csv file into multiple csv files depending on column value.
 Structure of csv file:  Name,Id,Dept,Course

```
abc,1,CSE,Btech 
fgj,2,EE,Btech
```

(Rows are not separated by ; at end)

If value of Dept is CSE or ME , write it to file1.csv, if value is ECE or EE write it to file2.csv and so on.

Can I use drools for this purpose? I don't know drools much.

Any help how it can be done?

This is what I have done yet:

```
public void run() {

    String csvFile = "C:/csvFiles/file1.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    BufferedWriter writer=null,writer2=null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
    String FileName = "C:/csvFiles/file3.csv";
    String FileName2 = "C:/csvFiles/file4.csv";

    try {

        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(FileName));
        writer2 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(FileName2));
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

               String[] values=line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            if(values[2].equals("CSE"))
            {
                writer.write(line);
            }
            else if(values[2].equals("ECE"))
            {
                writer2.write(line);
            }


        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                writer2.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show your effort?

Comment: sounds like homework. can you show your code so far?

Comment: this sounds like homework, also why would you use something as complex as drools to do something so simple.

Comment: Is your problem parsing the CSV? Use a 3rd party CSV library (e.g. [Ostermiller Utils](http://ostermiller.org/utils/CSV.html))?

Comment: Have you tried the split() method ?

Comment: Try the `String[] split(String regex)` method it should help you in this.

Comment: I am just exploring about methods of splitting.I cannot use any other 3rd party library and am trying to learn drools as well.So I thought of exploring whether it can be done with drools or not.

Comment: What have you done so far to solve the problem?

Comment: This is more easily solved with an `if` statement than with Drools.

Comment: Yes it can be done with if statements but just to learn about Drools I am thinking of that approach.

Comment: There are many much better ways of learning Drools. Don't break a butterfly on a wheel.

Answer (score 0):

1) First find column index using header row or if header is not present then by index

2) Follow below algorithm which will result map of key value where key is column by which split is performed

global resultMap;

```
Method add(key,row) {
        data = (resultMap.containsKey(key))? resultMap.get(key):new ArrayList<String>();
        data.add(row);
        resultMap.put(key, data );
    }

Method getSplittedMap(List rows) {
        for (String currentRow : rows) {
            add(key, currentRow);
        }
        return resultMap;
    }
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

```
FileOutputStream f_ECE = new FileOutputStream("provideloaction&filenamehere");
FileOutputStream f_CSE_ME = new FileOutputStream("provideloaction&filenamehere");
FileInputputStream fin = new FileinputStream("provideloaction&filenamehere");
int size = fin.available(); // find the length of file
byte b[] = new byte[size];
fin.read(b);
String s = new String(b); // file copied into string
String s1[] = s.split("\n");
for (int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
    String s3[] = s1[i].split(",")
    if (s3[2].equals("ECE"))
        f_ECE.write(s1.getBytes());
    if (s3[2].equals("CSE") || s3.equals("EEE"))
        f_CSE_ME.write(payload.getBytes());
}
```